# How to get IBM machine type from operating system level

Tags: redhat, ibm, bladecenter

I have spare IBM HS20, and HS40 Blade servers to use in my project, and I have to choose as modern as possible [RHEL release](https://hardware.redhat.com/list.cgi?product=Red%20Hat%20Hardware%20Certification&quicksearch=hs20) to install on it. My problem is that I don't know exact machine type of this blades (e.g 8843). Is there any possibility to get to know IBM machine type from operating system level? Actually they are running on RHEL3.

P.S. `dmidecode` is not an option for me. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to resort to the AMM of your BC and get that information via some scripting. `dmidecode`will return the BC slot number of that machine and you'll have to grep through the output of the AMM inventory that you can obtain via SSHing to it.

Comment: Wouldn't the web interface of the BC show this info as well?

Comment: sure, but you'll maybe want something non-interactive as you have to log into the webif.

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning AMM. I've totally forgotten about it. Web AMM GUI showed machine type.

Answer (score 0):

Try using lshw (even if it does not get the actual HS## number, there might be some parameter that has a value on HS20 and a different one on HS40 for example)